# Zend framework show database entry in form to update

Tags: php, mysql, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to edit particular row of table, before I want to show existing data in my form.
To show from i am using form decorator.
If I comment form decorator IT works fine.

I used  $form->populate($row); but its not filling form.

Please view below code for adminController.php

```
public function indexAction() {           
        $form = new Application_Form_articleForm();
        $this->view->form = $form; 
        $content  = new Application_Model_Content();  
        $id =  $this->_request->getParams('id');        
        $row = $content->find($id)->toArray();
        $form->populate($row[0]);
}
```

model file

```
<?php
class Application_Model_Content extends Zend_Db_Table
{
   protected $_name = "content";   

}
```

Form

```
<?php
class Application_Form_articleForm extends Zend_Form
{
   public function init()
   {
       $this->setMethod('post');      
       $id = $this->createElement('hidden','id');
       $content_name = $this->createElement('text','content_name');
       $content_name->setLabel('URL name:')
                   ->setAttrib('size',250);    

$this->addElements(array(  
           $id,               
           $content_name               
       ));

      $this->setDecorators(array(array('viewScript', array('viewScript' => 'admin/articleFormDecorator.phtml'))));
   }
}
```

articleFormDecorator.phtml

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <header><h3>Post New Article</h3></header>
                        <div class="module_content">
                            <fieldset>
                    <label>URL name</label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                            </fieldset>  
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Content</label>
                    <textarea rows="12" name="content_name" id="content_name"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
```

Please help me to get the values in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution
We need to add below line with form element in form

```
$content_name = $this->createElement('text','content_name');
       $content_name->setLabel('URL name:')
                   ->setAttrib('size',250);
```

and to show form element in html write as below in form decorator file

```
<?php echo $this->element->content_name ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add condition like this,

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
```

then the procedure for updating the values and storing them in databse

and in else part, you can populate the form like,

```
else{

            $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
            if ($id > 0) {
               $row = $content->find($id)->toArray();
               $form->populate($row[0]);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur ans. this works but I am using form decorator file to show html. How can I achieve this in form decorator.

Comment: well this should work as it is with form decorator also, just put the solution i suggest in controller,.

Comment: I did, It works if I comment line $this->setDecorators(array(array ... Is there any issue with form decorator file?

Comment: glad it helped, make sure your form's fields name and your database fields name which your fulling data with should be the same.

Comment: yes database fields are same. that's why I am getting values shown in form. issue is with form decorator but unable to find.

Comment: well then this question should be marked as solved and you should post it as another question.

Comment: no. there is issue with form decorator. that is written in question. I will accept once it get solved and gets current answer.